# Mappings between integer error codes and OpenSSL error constants

Tags: c, openssl, error-code

OpenSSL has a number of constants that it uses for errors. For example, `SSL_ERROR_NONE` means no error occurred, `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` means that not enough data was available, etc. You can find a complete list here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_error.html

In C, each of these constants is represented as an integer. Is there a way to find the mapping between the error codes and the actual integers that are used to hold them? For example, a page or a list in source code that says "0 is `ERROR_NONE`, 2 is `WANT_READ`", etc.

I tried reading through the source code for OpenSSL, but I could not find the constant definitions anywhere there.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? I.e., what is keeping you from using the named constants? I would assume the actual integers belong to the internal ("private") part of the library and can be different from one version to the next.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/openssl/blob/main/include/openssl/err.h) is a header that defines some error codes among other things, but I'm not seeing the two you've singled out verbatim.

Comment: I'm print line debugging by printing out the error codes, and it's easier to just print the integers than figure out what mapping I need to get the actual constants to show up in stderr.